# Where to get Google Apps(playstore,gmail,youtube etc) Source Code

Tags: android, embedded, porting

I am building android jelly bean for my development board,I need to build google store apps with this image,but through research i came to know that google apps source code is not open source.
In that case is there any way to get the google app source code?
Do i need to purchase google apps source code or i must have to use only google apps apks provided by google.

please suggest me a option to come out from this problem

Thanks you all in advance

Regards
Ajai

Comment: it's a closed source.

Answer (score 4):

> In that case is there any way to get the google app source code?

I have no idea if you can get the source code. Whether you can even license the APKs is up to Google. Quoting [the source.android.com FAQ](http://source.android.com/source/faqs.html#how-can-i-get-access-to-the-google-apps-for-android-such-as-maps):

> The Google apps for Android, such as YouTube, Google Maps and Navigation, Gmail, and so on are Google properties that are not part of Android, and are licensed separately. Contact android-partnerships@google.com for inquiries related to those apps.

Comment: And they are called GMS (Google Mobile Services)!